# C# Convolution algorithm is producing a very loud .wav file

Tags: c#, fft, convolution, audio-processing

I am trying to create a convolution reverb algorithm that takes a sound input signal and convolves it in the frequency domain with an impulse response. I have been trying to debug the code for a week and I cannot seem to find where the error is. The output of the algorithm is a .wav file that for some reason is very loud in the beginning but still sounds echoey at the end. I am using Aforge .net library[Link](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) to compute the FFT and the fault does not lie within the coding of that algorithm. Here is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using AForge.Math;
using NWaves.Operations.Convolution;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConvolutionReverbTest : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip input;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip impulseResponse;

// ir
private float[] irData;
private Complex[] irc;

// input
private float[] inputData;
private Complex[] inputc;

// conv. reverb values
private int fftSize = 0; // F = N + M - 1 --> Also to the power of 2

// muliplication in freq domain
private Complex[] multiplication;

// output signal
private float[] output;

private void Start() {
    GetAudioData();
    Convolve();
}

private void Convolve() {
    // calculate the fft of input data
    FourierTransform.FFT(inputc, FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);
    // calculate fft of impulse response
    FourierTransform.FFT(irc, FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);

    // multiply them in frequency domain
    multiplication = new Complex[fftSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < fftSize; i++) {
        multiplication[i] =  inputc[i] * irc[i];
        multiplication[i] *= fftSize; // normalize it
    }

    // calculate the ifft of the multiplication
    FourierTransform.FFT(multiplication, FourierTransform.Direction.Backward);

    // save output signal as wave file
    output = new float[fftSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < fftSize; i++) {
        output[i] = (float) multiplication[i].Re;
    }

    SaveOutputSignal(output);
}

private Complex ComplexMultiply(Complex a, Complex b) {
    return new Complex(a.Re * b.Re - a.Im * b.Im, a.Re * b.Im + a.Im * b.Re);
}

private void CalculateFftSize() {
    fftSize = Mathf.NextPowerOfTwo(inputData.Length + irData.Length - 1);
}

private void GetAudioData() {

    // get data of ir signal
    irData = new float[impulseResponse.samples];
    impulseResponse.GetData(irData, 0);
    // get data of input signal
    inputData = new float[input.samples];
    input.GetData(inputData, 0);

    CalculateFftSize();


    // change values accordingly of both signals --> zero padding + complex numbers
    irData = ZeroPadding(irData);
    irc = new Complex[irData.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < irData.Length; i++) {
        irc[i].Re = irData[i];
    }

    inputData = ZeroPadding(inputData);
    inputc = new Complex[inputData.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputData.Length; i++) {
        inputc[i].Re = inputData[i];
    }
}

private float[] ZeroPadding(float[] data) {
    List<float> newData = new List<float>(data);
    int N = data.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < (fftSize - N); i++) {
        newData.Add(0);
    }
    return newData.ToArray();
}

private void SaveOutputSignal(float[] outputSignal) {
    string filename = "outputSignal.txt";
    // save the output signal to a txt file
    File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, filename),
        outputSignal.Select(d => d.ToString()));


    new WaveFile().SaveAudio(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "output.wav"), outputSignal.Length, 1, outputSignal, input.frequency);
    }
}
```

Here is also a picture of the output signal in audacity:
[image: Audacity screenshot of output signal]

Any help is greatly appreciated.